# python kivy gui, click to activate

Tags: python, user-interface, events, kivy, click

I have created two Python Kivy apps that run simultaneously on a Windows OS (one launches the other from a sub-process). I have a problem where if you need to use the "other" app, you need to click on once in order to activate the it, before you can use any of its buttons, etc. This has caught me out a few times where I expected, in the moment, for the click to work first time.

Does anyone know if you can set Kivy to work on the first click?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I believe that is an issue with your desktop settings. What you describe is called `click to focus`.  There are other options for that setting, but `Kivy` is not the problem.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I will have a look for that setting and let you know the result!